# PDFMAKE: How to Repeat Array[ ] Items in 'content'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, pdfmake

I have an `Array within Items`. I want to repeat them in a Table like this in `PDFMake`.

```
table: {
      multiple pages
      headerRows: 2,
      widths: ['auto', 100, 200, 'auto', 'auto', 'auto'],

      body: [
        ['Nr.', 'Name', 'Beschreibung', 'Preis', 'Anzahl', 'MwSt(%)'],
        [bill.billItems[i].itemNumber, bill.billItems[i].name, bill.billItems[i].description, bill.billItems[i].price, bill.billItems[i].quantity, bill.billItems[i].vat],
            ]
   }
```

Does it give a simple way like `*ngFor` or `ngRepeat` in `PDFMake` or an other way like `for(i=0; i<array.length; i++)`

Answer (score 11):

You can use javascript variables in your docdefinition.
Try with the following :

```
// playground requires you to assign document definition to a variable called dd

var rows = [];
rows.push(['Nr.', 'Name', 'Beschreibung', 'Preis', 'Anzahl', 'MwSt(%)']);

for(var i of [1,2,3,4]) {
    rows.push(['#.'+i, 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx']);
}

var dd = {
    content: {
        table: {
                widths: ['*', 100, 200, '*', '*', '*'],
                body: rows
            }
    }

}
```

You can directly copy/paste this code in the [pdfmake playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) to see the live rendered PDF.

Comment: Awesome Job! @arnaud del.